# Как обратиться к статическому свойству из статического метода класса

Tags: php

```
Class A{
    public static $pdo;
    public static function getPDO(){
        return ????
    }

}
A::getPDO();
```

Как правильно сделать return $pdo?

Comment: `self::$pdo`, но смысла в методе `getPDO` нету, потому что переменная `$pdo` и так есть публичная.

Comment: если нужно свойство текущего класса, то с префиксом `self::`, а если из класса в контексте которого делается вызов, то `static::`. то что у вас написано, скорее всего придёт в итоге к шаблону Одиночка. можете сразу взять реализацию https://habr.com/post/31375/